# Recyling apppool using msbuild script

Tags: iis-7, msbuild

I'm using MSBuild to build and deploy the website, Before deploying i need to recycle the Application Pool, How can i do this from msbuild script?
(I do not want to restart the IIS just recycle the application pool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use the extension pack:
http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.4.0/index.html

It has a task:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7AppPool TaskAction="Recycle" Name="MyAppP"/>
```

That should do what you ask.

Answer (score 6):

The command is

```
c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool "MyAppPool"
```

You can execute it within msbuild target using `<Exec>` task.

Comment: When i execute i get this error         C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool "myapppool"
----->  ERROR ( message:Configuration error 
  
  Filename: redirection.config
  
  Line Number: 0
  
  Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
  
  . )

Comment: Controlling application tool requires elevated admin permissions. See more information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730918(WS.10).aspx. If your build process is elevated (i.e. started from elevated cmd window), then you should be able to control your application pool.

Comment: i tried to set permission like mentioned in this link http://silverbling.blogspot.com/2010/01/error-cannot-read-configuration-file.html but still no success

Comment: Iam using iis 7.5, my app pool is configured to "ApplicationPoolIdentity"