# Reset App Pool via Prebuild Command from VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, build, msbuild, msbuild-task

I am looking for a way to automatically reset the app pool in IIS7 when I run a build.  Currently I have to manually recycle the app pool before I deploy our code to our test server or the build breaks in TeamCity.

After some research it seems that a prebuild command is the answer.  I tried to follow the guidance to use the MSBuild Extension Pack from a similar apppool recycle [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556139/recyling-apppool-using-msbuild-script), but was unable to successfully implement it.  I downloaded the extension pack, and tried adding the suggested task in two elements in the .csproj:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>
  </PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
```

Any help either using the MSBuild Extension Pack or a different method would be helpful!

Comment: Can you confirm that the target server (the one you wish to recycle) is remote to the build server?

Answer (score 0):

Tried using Powershell yet for any part of your build process?  Have a look at:
https://serverfault.com/questions/223496/recycle-remote-iis-app-pool-from-the-command-line

Please also let us know a little more detail perhaps such as server O/S and relevant software...

Comment: Warning second link (ilovesharepoint) now leads to a NSFW site!

Comment: removed second link, thanks